# In Django, i can't see the user registration form on the home page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django, i would like to display the `register.html` registration form on the home page (`index.html`) and NOT on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/register` or similar. On the home page I want to see the various input textboxes. I don't get any errors, but the form doesn't display.

In the `index.html` page i don't use anything to call the form (`register.html`). Maybe I'm doing this wrong?

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

**App1/templates/registration/register.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %} 

<!--Register--> 
<div class="container py-5">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ register_form.as_p }}                    
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="/login">login</a> instead.</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**App1/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your forms here.

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**App1/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

**App1/views.py**

```
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
            return redirect("index.html")
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render (request=request, template_name="registation/register.html", context={"register_form":form})
```

**MYSITE (PROJECT)**

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App1.urls')),

    path("login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nodigap >

I think I got your problem.
Use the below code.

1. import your form
2. add form to context

```
from .forms import NewUserForm

def index(request):
    context={
      'register_form':NewUserForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You need all variables + forms to pass to this "context".

Answer (score 0):

have a look to App1/views.py at the end of the function.
it should return

```
return render(request, "registrazione/register.html",{"register_form":form})
```

the issue is the name of the directory is not matched as you mentioned
in templates directory
**templates/registrazione/register.html**
so **templates** is the base directory should be configured in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ["templates"], # here the templates should be mention
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

and in each views.py file return the .html file starting from sub-directory from templates/

so it should be in views.py file as mentioned above. but its better to rename **registrazione** from templates to **registration**
and from views.py file

```
return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form})
```

**imrovement**
app1/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
 path('', views.register_request, name='register_request'),
```

now it should be call as home page when you visit

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: If I use your return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form}), request and form are underlined as if they were an error. Do I need to import something? And in setting.py, in Templates, I had written "DIRS": [ BASE_DIR / "templates" ]. Was this right too or was it wrong?
​

Comment: Also, how should I insert the form into the home page (index.html)? Could you revise your solution a little please? It doesn't help me at the moment

Comment: you dont need to import anything. just add the app name app1 to installed variable in settings.py.

if you need to set the home page as register page. you just need to set the path.

projectname/urls.py

[
path('', include('app1.urls.py'))
]

app1/urls.py
[
remove the index from here
path('', views.register_request, name='index'),

]

visit
http://127.0.0.1:8000 instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

Comment: I didn't understand, but because in the comment it's not clear how you wrote. Could you improve your answer and show me what you say please? I will be happy to accept your reply in case of any help

Comment: UPDATE: The cause of the problem was {% include 'registration/register.html' %}. I deleted it. Now the website opens correctly, without errors, BUT I don't see the form on the home page. Should I write something in index.html to call the form?

Answer (score 0):

You should include your register.html in your index                                               `<body>                                                                                                    {% include 'registrazione/register.html' %}                                                    </body>`

Comment: @CaousWT I'm getting an error with your solution. I receive: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
App1/registration/register.html

Comment: remove template_name in this line `return render(request, "registrazione/register.html",{"register_form":form}) ` also your "DIRS": [ BASE_DIR / "templates" ] is true

Comment: So should I continue to use my return render (request=request, template_name="registation/register.html", context={"register_form":form}) and also my "DIRS": [ BASE_DIR / "templates" ]? Were they both correct?
​

Comment: No, `return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form})` this line should be like this. if you assign your file path to template_name ` template_name = "registration/register.html" `you would write like this ` return render(request, template_name , {"register_form":form})`

Comment: i dont see your app paths include it correctly

Comment: I'm getting confused. So I have to use return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form}) and then your new {% include 'registration/register.html' %}. Right? If I use return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form}), the words request and form get underlined and give me an error. Do I need to import something? Can you improve your answer please?

Comment: can you share the path where register.html is in the templates directory

Comment: Which file are you referring to?

Comment: i'm asking where your register.html is.

Comment: App1/templates/registration/register.html

Comment: do u have another templates dir

Comment: I do not understand you. If you understand what my problem is, could you edit and improve your answer please? If you have any other questions, just ask me

Comment: what is error when you include registration.html

Comment: RecursionError at /
maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Just add ` {% block content %} {% endblock  %}` to body in index